# JAXB with multiple XSD

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

i am trying  to use tha jaxb to marshall xml 
i used the xjc command to generate java classes from an xsd file : order.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- version 2.10 -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="c.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="csa" type="param"/>
<xsd:complexType name="param">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="User" type="alpha50" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Infos" type="infosType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Params_Leg" type="params_LegType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Commande" type="commandeType"/>
    </xsd:all>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:decimal"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- Atos / Command Parameters tree type -->
<xsd:complexType name="commandeType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="Mode" type="modeType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Etat" type="etatType"/>
                       <xsd:element name"IP" type="urlType">
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I get many annotated classes however none of them @XmlRootElement(name = "Order") and no classe named Order

Answer (score 0):

A class will be generated for each complex type and global elements with anonymous complex types.  In your XML schema it appears as though the root element is `csa`.  The `csa` element has a named complex type called `param` so you will want to create an instance of `Param`.  The generated `ObjectFactory` class will have a convenience method for wrapping it in the `csa` element.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: great turorial , it really helped